# Проблема с реализацией эффекта вычитания шейдерами HLSL

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, hlsl

Я столкнулся с проблемой в моем проекте и нуждаюсь в помощи.

Я хочу реализовать эффект вычитания. То есть есть два объекта: *вычитающий(назовём **Вычитатель**)* и *от которого вычитают(назовём **Платформа**)*, и на месте их пересечения пиксели **платформы** не должны отображаться, а **срез** между ними заполняется каким-то цветом.
Примеры как это должно выглядеть:
[image: Пример 1]

[image: Пример 2]

Чтобы это реализовать я создал 3 шейдера:
***Вычитателя:***

```
Shader "Custom/Subtractor_Shader"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue" = "Geometry+1"}

        ZWrite off
        ColorMask 0

        Stencil
        {
            Ref 2
            Comp equal
        }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex: POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos: SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i): COLOR
            {
                return half4(0,1,0,1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

***Платформы:***

```
Shader "Mobile/Fog_shader"
{
    Properties
    {
        ...
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{"Queue"="Geometry"}
        Fog{ Mode off }
        LOD 200

        Stencil
        {
            ref 2
            Comp always
            Pass replace
        }

        Pass
        {
           ... //Код цвета пикселя
        }
    }
    Fallback "Mobile/VertexLit"
}
```

**Среза:**

```
Shader "Custom/Slice"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue" = "Geometry+2"}

        Stencil
        {
            Ref 2
            Comp equal
            Pass keep 
            ZFail decrWrap
        }

        Pass
        {
            ZTest Less

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex: POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos: SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i): COLOR
            {
                return half4(1,0,1,1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что **Вычитатель** не отбрасывает пиксели от **платформы**.
Как это выглядит:[image: Как это выглядит]

Хотя если мы закомментируем`//ColorMask 0` в **Вычитателе**, то увидим это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уточнение: Шейдер должен подходить под **мобильные устройства**